# AWS API Gateway {"error": "missing authentication token"}

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda

I've been constantly getting the "missing authentication token" error when I click the AWS API gateway POST method url through the browser. I set "AUTH" as none and it's working totally fine through Postman but not with the browser. The problem is that I'm using swift to trigger the method and it doesn't seem to be reaching the gateway at all (no log on CloudWatch) and I don't think my code is wrong (or maybe it is). If someone could point out what my mistake is or a solution to this problem I'd appreciate it so much.

P.S. My lambda function is working totally fine and I typed in the right URL (one in the code is just for example)

Here's my code:

```
func postNonceToServer(paymentMethodNonce: String) {

    let paymentURL = URL(string: "https://example-url.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/create-transaction")!
    var request = URLRequest(url: paymentURL)
    request.httpBody = "\(paymentMethodNonce)".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
}
```

Comment: Do not post pictures of code. Please [edit] your question by copying and pasting your relevant code into your question as properly formatted text. Pictures are hard to read, can't be searched, and can't be referenced in answers.

Comment: @rmaddy thanks for the feedback, I updated the code!

Comment: Are you sure you have method and resource for this query in api gateway? Just check it.

Comment: @DmitryGrinko yes I have both the method and the resource set up. Even testing works, but it's just the browser that doesn't give me what I want

Comment: Do you remember about re-deploy API?  Just check it.

Comment: @DmitryGrinko yup I re-deployed every time I made changes and I can't seem to figure it out :(

Comment: Method Request > Authorization : none ? right?

Comment: @DmitryGrinko yes, it works using Postman but not on the browser that's what's confusing me

Comment: I think you should get more information about this error in your browser's console.

Answer (score 3):

After enabling CORS on my endpoints I was receiving the same error message:

```
{"message":"Missing Authentication Token"}
```

Everything checked out, but I consistently received that error. To fix my issue I had to deploy the API. To do that, do the following:

1. Go to "Amazon API Gateway" console
2. Click on the API Gateway in question
3. Click "Resources" and select the root resource, e.g., "/"
4. Click "Actions" and then "Deploy API"
5. Select the stage you want to deploy to
6. Click "Deploy"

Long story short, redeploy the API after you've enabled CORS.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, this should be a problem in the URL itself. I can think of:

1- Please make sure that the URL is parsed correctly by printing it to the console and pasting it into the browser URL bar. (I have no idea about swift)

2- Make sure that "execute-api" is included in your "example-url", i.e., before the region.

3- Make sure that OPTIONS method has AUTH as none.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I realized that I didn't have to make it work on the browser since it works on swift now

Answer (score 0):

This mostly would be because of CORS issue.

Please enable CORS in you API gateway like below. After enabling CORS please redeploy the API

If you don't have OPTIONS added, please follow below steps (If OPTIONS already there just add CORS),

- Create a new OPTIONS method under the /services resource
- Create and populate the Access-Control-Allow-Origin/Method/Headers in the OPTIONS method.

Enable CORS like below after creating OPTIONS

[image]

Comment: Actually it doesn't look like an CORS issue

Comment: I tried all of the things you mentioned but I'm still getting the error. Is there another way to make this work on the browser?

Comment: did you try all different browsers? Also can you please open developer tools console while requesting through the browser and see if there any specific error writing in the console.